# I want to get a token with Azure Graph and execute Teams API(C#)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

After I authenticate with Azure Graph to get a token, I want to use that token to create a Teams online meeting.

When I create an online meeting in Teams, the response contains an error with status code 501.

How do I create an online meeting?

App flow

1. Start the app
2. Make a GET request (https://localhost:43321/api)
3. GetAsync method is executed
4. Get token with GetToken method
5. Create a meeting in Teams "online Meetings"

```
[Route("api")]
[ApiController]
public class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ContentResult> GetAsync()
    {
        var result = GetToken();
        string accessToken = result.Result.access_token;

        var httpClient = new WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Services.HttpClient();
        var meetingData = new MeetingData
        {
            StartDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 8, 10, 12, 57, 0),
            EndDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 8, 10, 13, 12, 0),
            Subject = "meeting"
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(meetingData, Formatting.Indented);
        (var res, var statusCode) = await httpClient.PostHttpContentWithToken("me/onlineMeetings", accessToken, json);

        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MeetingData>(res);

        return Content(res);
    }
}
```

```
private async Task<AccessTokenClass> GetToken()
{
    string tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token";
    var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

    tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
        ["client_id"] = "clientId",
        ["client_secret"] = "clientSecret",
        ["scope"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    });

    var results = new AccessTokenClass();
    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

    var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

    var json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);

    return results;
}
```

The app is registered in azure ad.

"ClientId", "tenantId", "clientSecret" inside GetToken method sets the information of Overview of Azure Portal.

The API setting is the state of the image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

client_credentials flow is not supported for creating online meeting.

You should use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)(require user interaction) or [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)(not recommended by Microsoft due to security).

Please check it.